# ElasticSearch and Agregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have been given a problem where I need to perform a search based on different fields.For example,On UI the user is giving several search option like company name,department,state/province,title country and region.

The user selects few of these options like company name,department,state.I need to perform the search on these fields and return the results.

Can I do this with the help of aggregation in elastic search?Can anyone give me detailed example on how this can be done.

I did a few example like performing aggregation on gender.the query is as follows:-
"aggs" :{"group_by_gender" :{"terms" :{"field" : "gender"}}

When I ran this type of query all the sources(from documents) were returned.So,I was kind of confused whether aggregation is actually performed.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aggregations](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html) are meant to make statistics over the values of fields. If you need to search documents depending on fields, you need to make ([boolean](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)) queries.

Example:

```
POST myIndex/_search
{
    "bool" : {
        "must" : [
            {"term" : { "name" : "kimchy" }},
            {"term" : { "state" : "unicorn planet" }}
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Elastic search boolquery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

boolean query has different parameters like must , should , match ,match all , filter.
hope this will help.